# Huawei erecovery not working on Honor 7 lite(forgotten password lock)

Tags: usb-debugging

Can anyone help with this ? 
I can´t really get into settings to change usb debugging. Also huawei erecovery asks about update(Download latest version and recovery) -- which results in error getting package info failed.

Not sure how to proceed in this, because bootloader is also locked.

Any ideas ?